# 2022: La moderación del sitio

Tags: discusión, moderación, estadísticas

Mientras nos despedimos del año anterior y damos la bienvenida al año nuevo, tenemos la [tradición de compartir las estadísticas de moderación del año pasado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year%20in%20moderation%22%20is%3Aquestion).

Como la mayoría de ustedes saben, los sitios en la red de Stack Exchange se moderan de manera algo diferente a otros sitios en la web:

> Diseñamos el motor de red de Stack Exchange para que sea mayormente autorregulado, en el sentido de que amortizamos el costo general de moderación del sistema a través de miles de diminutas porciones de esfuerzo aportadas por usuarios regulares y cotidianos.
>
> -- [Teoría de la moderación](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Eso no elimina por completo la necesidad de tener [moderadores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/), pero significa que la mayor parte del trabajo de moderación lo llevan a cabo gente normal. Cada esfuerzo que ustedes hacen para contribuir al sitio les da acceso a más privilegios que pueden usar para ayudar en este esfuerzo, esto produce un efecto que hace una gran diferencia.

Entonces, mientras nos despedimos del 2022 (y adónde fue enero, ¿no?) y nos sumergimos de cabeza en 2023, echemos un vistazo a lo que logramos como comunidad... mirando algunas [estadísticas emocionantes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TPg.gif).

A continuación se muestra un desglose de las acciones de moderación realizadas en Stack Overflow en español durante los últimos 12 meses:

| Acción | Moderadores | Comunidad¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Todos los comentarios en una publicación movidos a un chat | 44 | 0 |
| Reportes de Respuesta gestionados | 5,742 | 1,086 |
| Respuestas reportadas | 4 | 6,739 |
| Reportes de comentario gestionados | 570 | 159 |
| Comentarios eliminados⁷ | 2,037 | 8,760 |
| Comentarios reportados | 0 | 730 |
| Comentarios recuperados | 21 | 0 |
| Escaladas al equipo de Community Managers | 4 | 0 |
| Publicaciones promocionadas | 0 | 8,274 |
| Publicaciones eliminadas⁶ | 3,256 | 21,178 |
| Publicaciones bloqueadas | 1 | 35 |
| Publicaciones Recuperadas | 78 | 655 |
| Publicaciones Desbloqueadas | 0 | 1 |
| Reportes en preguntas gestionados⁵ | 932 | 3,240 |
| Preguntas Cerradas | 1,367 | 4,642 |
| Preguntas Reportadas⁵ | 51 | 4,234 |
| Preguntas Migradas | 4 | 1 |
| Preguntas Protegidas | 1 | 91 |
| Preguntas reabiertas | 61 | 55 |
| Revisiones redactadas | 15 | 0 |
| Sinónimos de Etiqueta creados | 3 | 0 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Votos de Cierre | 7 | 3,770 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Primeras Respuestas | 5 | 6,421 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Primeras Preguntas | 27 | 16,928 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Respuestas Tardías | 13 | 3,421 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Publicaciones de Baja Calidad | 0 | 4,656 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Votos de Reapertura | 66 | 608 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Ediciones Sugeridas | 96 | 8,735 |
| Usuarios contactados | 24 | 0 |
| Usuarios borrados | 13 | 0 |
| Usuarios destruidos³ | 30 | 0 |
| Usuarios suspendidos² | 20 | 19 |

**Notas**

¹ "Comunidad" aquí se refiere tanto a [los miembros de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users) sin [diamantes junto a sus nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), como a los sistemas automatizados conocidos como [usuario #-1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad).

² El sistema suspenderá a los usuarios en tres circunstancias: cuando un usuario es recreado después de haber sido suspendido previamente, cuando un usuario es recreado después de haber sido destruido por spam o abuso, y cuando una suspensión en toda la red está en efecto en una cuenta.

³ Un usuario "destruido" es eliminado junto con todo lo que había publicado: preguntas, respuestas, comentarios. (Generalmente se utiliza como una forma expeditiva de deshacerse del spam) ([What is the difference between a deleted user and a "destroyed" user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user))

⁴ Esto cuenta cada revisión que fue enviada (no saltada) - así que las 2 revisiones de ediciones sugeridas necesarias para aprobar una edición contarían como 2, el objetivo es indicar la frecuencia de las acciones de moderación. Esto también se aplica a los reportes, etc.

⁵ Incluye cerrar reportes (pero no cerrar o reabrir votaciones).

⁶ Esto ignora las numerosas eliminaciones que ocurren automáticamente en respuesta a alguna otra acción.

⁷ Esto incluye los comentarios borrados por sus propios autores (que también suponen un cierto número de reportes de comentarios gestionados).

### Más lecturas:

- También puede consultar este [informe sobre otros sitios](https://stackexchange.com/nocaptcha?returnUrl=%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dtitle%253A%25222022%253A%2Ba%2Byear%2Bin%2Bmoderation%2522)
- O consultar la [información detallada sobre el número de preguntas cerradas y reabiertas en todos los sitios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386090/2022-a-year-in-closing)

¡Les deseo a todos un feliz 2023! ^_^

Comment: Interestingly it seems that moderators don't care at all about low-quality posts

Comment: Tenemos pocos moderadores, si esa cola no crece demasiado y el resto de los usuarios ya la van limpiando es normal que le dediquen poco o nada de su tiempo.

Comment: le falto dos columnas a ese reporte ... no se deja ver que hay pendiente y cuanto es el total existente XD