# 2023: La moderación del sitio

Tags: discusión, moderación, estadísticas

¡Es ese tiempo del año otra vez! Mientras nos despedimos del año anterior y damos la bienvenida al año nuevo, tenemos la [tradición de compartir las estadísticas de moderación del año pasado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

Como la mayoría de ustedes saben, los sitios en la red de Stack Exchange se moderan de manera algo diferente a otros sitios en la web:

> Diseñamos el motor de red de Stack Exchange para que sea mayormente autorregulado, en el sentido de que amortizamos el costo general de moderación del sistema a través de miles de diminutas porciones de esfuerzo aportadas por usuarios regulares y cotidianos.
> -- [Teoría de la moderación](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Eso no elimina por completo la necesidad de tener [moderadores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/), pero significa que la mayor parte del trabajo de moderación lo llevan a cabo gente normal - como tú. Cada esfuerzo que hacen para contribuir al sitio les da acceso a más privilegios que pueden usar para ayudar en este esfuerzo, esto produce un efecto que hace una gran diferencia para asegurar que los sitios de Stack Exchange permanecen como una fuente valiosa de contenido de alta calidad en la web.

Entonces, mientras nos despedimos del 2023 (y adónde fue enero, ¿no?) y nos sumergimos de cabeza en 2024, echemos un vistazo a lo que logramos como comunidad... mirando algunas [estadísticas emocionantes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmN7M.gif).

A continuación se muestra un desglose de las acciones de moderación realizadas en Stack Overflow en español durante los últimos 12 meses:

| Acción | Moderadores | Usuario Comunidad¹ | Comunidad² |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Todos los comentarios en una publicación movidos a un chat | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| Reportes de Respuesta gestionados | 4,023 | 546 | 0 |
| Respuestas reportadas | 2 | 1,287 | 3,221 |
| Recompensas canceladas | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Reportes de comentario gestionados | 383 | 41 | 9 |
| Comentarios borrados⁸ | 730 | 104 | 3,666 |
| Comentarios reportados | 1 | 7 | 423 |
| Comentarios recuperados | 38 | 0 | 0 |
| Escaladas al equipo de Community Manager | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| Publicaciones promocionada | 0 | 8,208 | 0 |
| Publicaciones borradas⁷ | 2,972 | 10,605 | 3,825 |
| Publicaciones bloqueadas | 0 | 34 | 0 |
| Publicaciones recuperadas | 76 | 1 | 298 |
| Publicaciones desbloqueadas | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Reportes en preguntas gestionados⁶ | 678 | 1,260 | 694 |
| Preguntas cerradas | 1,209 | 1,775 | 43 |
| Preguntas reportadas⁶ | 24 | 56 | 2,575 |
| Preguntas combinadas | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Preguntas migradas | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Preguntas protegidas | 0 | 102 | 2 |
| Preguntas reabiertas | 20 | 28 | 1 |
| Preguntas desprotegidas | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Revisiones redactadas | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| Etiquetas: lenguaje de resaltado especificado | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Etiquetas: sinónimos creados | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Etiquetas: sinónimos propuestos | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Etiquetas: combinadas | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Tareas de revisión⁵: cola Votos de Cierre | 227 | 0 | 1,874 |
| Tareas de revisión⁵: cola Primeras Respuestas | 8 | 0 | 3,933 |
| Tareas de revisión⁵: cola Primeras Preguntas | 9 | 0 | 10,097 |
| Tareas de revisión⁵: cola Respuestas Tardías | 5 | 0 | 2,435 |
| Tareas de revisión⁵: cola Publicaciones de Baja Calidad | 27 | 0 | 4,361 |
| Tareas de revisión⁵: cola Votos de Reapertura | 29 | 0 | 292 |
| Tareas de revisión⁵: cola Ediciones Sugeridas | 49 | 368 | 4,144 |
| Tareas de revisión⁵: cola de Triaje | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Suspensiones de usuarios para revisar | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Suspensiones de usuarios para revisar (eliminada) | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Usuarios bloqueados | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Usuarios contactados | 64 | 0 | 0 |
| Usuarios borrados | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| Usuarios destruidos⁴ | 22 | 0 | 0 |
| Usuarios suspendidos³ | 55 | 9 | 0 |

**Notas**

¹ Esto se refiere a los sistemas automáticos conocidos como [user #-1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² Esto se refiere a [los miembros de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users) **sin** [diamantes junto a sus nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)

³ El sistema suspenderá a los usuarios en tres circunstancias: cuando un usuario es recreado después de haber sido suspendido previamente, cuando un usuario es recreado después de haber sido destruido por spam o abuso, y cuando una suspensión en toda la red está en efecto en una cuenta.

⁴ Un usuario "destruido" es eliminado junto con todo lo que había publicado: preguntas, respuestas, comentarios. (Generalmente se utiliza como una forma expeditiva de deshacerse del spam) ([What is the difference between a deleted user and a "destroyed" user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user))

⁵ Esto cuenta cada revisión que fue enviada (no saltada) - así que las 2 revisiones de ediciones sugeridas necesarias para aprobar una edición contarían como 2, el objetivo es indicar la frecuencia de las acciones de moderación. Esto también se aplica a los reportes, etc.

⁶ Incluye cerrar reportes (pero no cerrar o reabrir votaciones).

⁷ Esto ignora las numerosas eliminaciones que ocurren automáticamente en respuesta a alguna otra acción.

⁸ Esto incluye los comentarios borrados por sus propios autores (que también suponen un cierto número de reportes de comentarios gestionados).

### Más lecturas:

- También puede consultar este [informe sobre otros sitios](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222023%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- O consultar la [información detallada sobre el número de preguntas cerradas y reabiertas en todos los sitios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396299/208518)

¡Les deseo a todos un feliz 2024! ^_^

Comment: Pero aquí faltan estadísticas, por ejemplo cuántas publicaciones se hicieron, cuántas respuestas se dieron, de estás cuantas fueron aceptadas, además contra que año comparó, cual es la tendencia de un año para otro. Además, esta comunidad es en español, yo no voy a la comunidad inglesa a escribir en español escribo en inglés, por tanto aquí también se tiene que respetar eso, sea quien sea

Comment: no veo la estadisticas de cuantas veces se intento contactar al CM de parte de los usuarios y cuantas veces contesto ... XD

Comment: @Japv los post de trabajadores/community managers de Stack Overflow siempre están en inglés y los moderadores (o cualquier miembro de la comunidad) los traduce. No es cuestión de ir al sitio en inglés a escribir en español (o viceversa). Y sí, estaría bien tener más números para poner estos en contexto.

Comment: Voy a traducir (con ayuda del [post del año pasado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5527/2022-la-moderaci%c3%b3n-del-sitio) que tiene básicamente el mismo contenido).